# CASE expression syntax in Computed Column not working

Tags: case, expression

I'm trying to write a CASE expression that evaluates the data in a field called "MembershipType," and makes a logical computed column go from false to true if any of the following are entered:

MembershipType = EX-MEMBER
-or-
MembershipType = NON-ACTIVE
-or-
MembershipType = DECEASED

*I can write it as the first part and it works fine:*

case when [membershiptype]='Ex-Member' then (1) else (0) end

*But I can't figure out the correct syntax to add the other options.  This doesn't work:*

case when [membershiptype]='Ex-Member' then (1) else (0), [membershiptype]='Non-Active' then (1) else (0), [membershiptype]='Deceased' then (1) else (0) end

Answer (score 0):

I think you want:

```sql
CASE WHEN [membershiptype] IN ('Ex-Member', 'Non-Active', 'Deceased') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
```

Comment: Ah, that is perfect!  I see now where I was writing the expression incorrectly.  Thank you!